# How can I display the contents of more than one cell that satisfies a certain condition?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a row of cells that contain the numbers `16, 16, 28, 18, 22` within the range `K13:O13` and a row of cells with the strings `ruben, carter, akko, mostrino, Jaycee` within the range `K1:O1`. I have a formula that outputs the value of the cell in the second range when the value of the cell in the *first range* in the same column meets a condition.  The formula, which finds the minimum value of the cells in `K13:O13` is this: `=INDEX(K$1:O$1, 1, MATCH(MIN(K13:O13), K13:O13, 0))`.  The result of this formula is `ruben`, but I have multiple cells, `K13` and `O13`, whose values are the smallest in the given range, so the output should ideally be `ruben, carter`.

**How can I modify my formula to output *every* cell value (separated by a comma) that corresponds to another cell that satisfies a condition?**  For example, if I have the range `K13:Q13` with the following values `4, 6, 4, 4, 9, 5, 8, 7` and the range `K1:Q1` with values `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h`, the cell containing the desired formula should contain the text `a, c, d`.

A solution that uses Google Apps-Script would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:H2),
 "select Col2 where Col1 matches '"&MIN(A1:H1)&"'")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: How can I make this work if the row with the returned values isn't connected to the values that `MIN` is being applied to? I tried `=TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(K13:O13&K1:O1),
 "select Col2 where Col1 matches '"&MIN(K13:O13)&"'")))`  where `K13:O13` contains the values that MIN is applied to and `K1:O1` contains the returned values, but this returned a `#VALUE! (An array value could not be found)` error.

Comment: try: `=TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({K13:O13;K1:O1}), "select Col2 where Col1 matches '"&MIN(K13:O13)&"'")))`

Comment: This works, I forgot I had to actually put it as an array.